# QComboBox can't change border color

Tags: qt, colors, border, frame, qcombobox

I have a class which inherits QComboBox. I need to set red border for this widget.
I can't use QPalette, I am trying to use setStyleSheet:
`pComboBox->setStyleSheet("QFrame { border: 2px solid red; }")`
It works fine for QLineEdit, but for QComboBox I got red border around popup view and not combo box.
How can I get access to the frame of QComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the easiest way, which I found to solve this problem is just to subclass widget I use and draw red rectangle in paintEvent().

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `QComboBox` selector, not `QFrame` (or both if you want the two styled).

```
pComboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox { border: 2px solid red; } QFrame { border: 2px solid blue; }")
```

See the [StyleSheet examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox) for more on styling that widget.

Comment: That works for QComboBox, but with setting of this style QComboBox looks like Win95 combo box, not XP. And that doesn't work at all for the widget I use (which inherits QComboBox). Even if I use class name of my widget with setStyleSheet :(

Comment: I have tried all the ways I found. Now I am wondering whether it's good idea to add one more QFrame for SomeComboBox and use it to make red border....

Comment: As soon as you stylize a combo box Qt can no longer use the native OS version of it (and you're breaking the native look anyway by stylizing it).  So if you intend to mess with the combo box's style you have to customize pretty much the whole widget.

Comment: @Funt, just as an idea: Why not use QPalette to set the **background** color of your combobox? Instead of having a colored frame, the whole box is highlighted. And you keep the native OS style intact.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use QPalette. Class which I have to use (inherits QComboBox) ignores setting of QPalette and uses its own colours. Also border looks better than red background for me.    What is the best way to add my own extra QFrame to QComboBox?

Comment: @Funt: simply including your combo box inside a QFrame should work.